# How to specify the client ID and redirect URI in Swagger OAuth2.0 configuration for Swagger UI?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, swagger, openapi, swagger-ui

Consider the following OpenAPI OAuth2 security scheme definition:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    oauth2_auth_code:
      type: oauth2
      description: Authorize with OAuth2
      flows:
        authorizationCode:
          authorizationUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/1d063515-6cad-4195-9486-ea65df456faa/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
          tokenUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/1d063515-6cad-4195-9486-ea65df456faa/oauth2/v2.0/token
          refreshUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/1d063515-6cad-4195-9486-ea65df456faa/oauth2/v2.0/token
          scopes:
            api://779d25c3-6c74-4875-b5ae-ef9b5a04b1e8/user_impersonation: Access Application
```

This results in Swagger UI displaying available authorizations as:

[image]

I don't want users to specify the client_id (it should be provided by developers). Furthermore, client_secret is not relevant here, and should not be displayed.

How can I configure the client_id, client_secret, and redirect URI in the OpenAPI spec, so Swagger UI will not prompt users to enter it themselves?

Reference:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/

Comment: you're not giving us the relevant part of your OAS description where the security object is defined at the root or at each path item.  the `components/securitySchemes` is just a reusable component definition.

Comment: The security is just `oauth2_auth_code: []`